# Multiple Raspyberry Pi 3. One of them has steady red light

Tags: pi-3, power

I have 2 Pis. One of the Pis boot up and the red light goes away and the second Raspberry Pi boots up but the **red light stays steady**. I have not connected any peripherals to any of the Pis and I access the Pis through ssh. FYI the green light keeps blinking on both the Pis. Installed Hypriot OS on both. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem. The red lights are supposed to stay on.

If they are off, it means that there is not enough voltage. You will also see a thunderbolt logo on the screen if there is a monitor attached.

I suggest getting a better power adapter. Make sure it can supply around 2A, especially if you have peripherals. A good example would be a charger for a flagship phone.

---

**Addendum:** The cable can also be a *major* factor with power delivery. I still encountered the problem even though I was using a known good adapter. It turns out the cheap $1 cables were to blame. Replaced all my cables with brand-name ones 6 months ago, and the problem was gone for good.

I had another non-critical unit that had the same problem. I put the blame on the power adapter, but when the cable was replaced, the problem disappeared. Same scenario with a phone that charged slowly.

It had the added benefit of me not replacing cables every ~5 weeks.